# Assigning random centroids by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to assign a random centroid for a 2D data (i.e. each 2D point should be assigned to a single centroid randomly chosen in advance from the data points).

`Code 1` demonstrates a simple example where:

- `points` is a `numpy.array` object which contains 10 2D data points.
- 5 random point indices (that correspond to indices of points in the `points` array) are being chosen as the initial cluster centroids.
- a `pandas.DataFrame` is being created with the 10 points from the `points` array, with labels corresponding to points' coordinate (i.e. `x1` and `x2`).

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

points = np.array(
    [
        [ 4.5,  7.0],
        [ 8.8,  7.7],
        [-9.2, -7.2],
        [-1.3,  6.9],
        [-5.7, -8.3],
        [ 8.8, -2.8],
        [-3.8, -6.7],
        [ 1.3,  4.5],
        [ 9.4,  8.5],
        [ 0.4,  1.5],
    ]
)

init_centroids_idx = np.random.choice(points.shape[0], n_clusters, replace=False)
print(f'initial centroid indices: {init_centroids_idx}')

data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': points[:, 0],
        'x2': points[:, 1]
    }
)
data_df
```

**Requirement:**

- Randomly assign each point in `data_df` to a single centroid from `points` that are determined by the point indices in `centroids`, so that the resulting `data_df` would be like in `Example 1`.

**Example 1:**

If the chosen centroid indices are:

```
init_centroids_idx = [9, 7, 8, 5, 2]
```

then the corresponding data points from `points` array, that represent the centroids are:

```
initial centroids (points): [[ 0.4,  1.5], [ 1.3,  4.5], [ 9.4,  8.5], [ 8.8, -2.8], [-9.2, -7.2]]
```

so, the final `data_df` should have:

- two more columns, i.e. `centroid_x1` and `centroid_x2`, which will correspond to the coordinates of the points in the `initial_centroids`, and will be assigned randomly to each data point.
- the centroids themselves will have their oun coordinates as the centroid).

**Example of the desired output:**

[image]

**Note:**

- The first two points are assigned to cluster centroid 2, third point is assigned to centroid point in the 9'th index etc.
- Centroids themselves (i.e. points that correspond to indices 2, 5, 7, 8, 9) are being assigned to themselves.

**My Question:**

What is the best way to accomplish requirement?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A mistake - corrected. Thanks.

Comment: So everything works with your solution. What do you mean by "more elegant"?

Comment: I mean is there a way to solve it in less lines of code? I.e. is there a method in `numpy`, or other module, that can accomplish this task? For example instead of using the `choice` twice do it in one take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by:

1. producing a random vector with the `numpy.random.choice()` method
2. producing sample of points which indices correspond to the sampled indices in the random vector, of length of the number of the points in `points` array, as shown in `Code`.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

points = np.array(
    [
        [ 4.5,  7.0],
        [ 8.8,  7.7],
        [-9.2, -7.2],
        [-1.3,  6.9],
        [-5.7, -8.3],
        [ 8.8, -2.8],
        [-3.8, -6.7],
        [ 1.3,  4.5],
        [ 9.4,  8.5],
        [ 0.4,  1.5],
    ]
)

init_centroids_idx = choice(points.shape[0], n_clusters, replace=False)
print(f'initial centroid indices: {init_centroids_idx}')

centroid_idx_2_point = choice(init_centroids_idx, points.shape[0], replace=True)
centroid_idx_2_point[np.sort(centroid_idx_2_point)] = np.sort(centroid_idx_2_point)  # replacing the centroids with themselves
print(f'centroid index to point assignment vector: {centroid_idx_2_point}')

point_2_centroid = points[centroid_idx_2_point]
print(f'point-centroid assignment vector: \n{point_2_centroid}')

data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': points[:, 0],
        'x2': points[:, 1],
        'centroid_x1': point_2_centroid[:, 0],
        'centroid_x2': point_2_centroid[:, 1],
    }
)
data_df
```

Though, I'd appreciate any sort of improvement suggestions regarding my code, i.e. make it more elegant/efficient (by replacing the two `choice` calls by one method that does the same for example).

Thanks.